# Is it possible to optimise this number crunching algorithm further?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to do some data crunching in Python and I have a nested loop that does some arithmetic calculations. The inner loop is executed 20.000 times so the following piece of code takes a long time:

```
for foo in foo_list:
    # get bar_list for foo
    for bar in bar_list:
        # do calculations w/ foo & bar
```

Could this loop be faster using Numpy or Scipy?

Comment: What calculations are you doing?

Comment: It depends, You've got to determine exactly which calculation is taking the longest.  If access to foo and bar are taking too long because it has to wait to pull it from the read write head of the hard drive, then optimizing the nature of the loop is focusing on the wrong area.

Answer (score 2):

Use Numpy:

```
import numpy as np
foo = np.array(foo_list)[:,None]
bar = np.array(bar_list)[None,:]
```

Then

```
foo + bar
```

or other operation creates an array `len(foo) * len(bar)` with the respective results.

Example:

```
>>> foo_list = [10, 20, 30]
>>> bar_list = [4, 5]
>>> foo = np.array(foo_list)[:,None]
>>> bar = np.array(bar_list)[None,:]
>>> 2 * foo + bar

array([[24, 25],
       [44, 45],
       [64, 65]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used numpy for image processing. Before I was using for(x in row) { for y in column} (or vice-versa, you get the idea).

That was fine for small images but would happily consume ram. Instead I switched to numpy.array. Much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what is actually going on in your loop, yes.
numpy allows use of arrays and matrices, which allows indexing making execution of your code faster and, in some cases, can eliminate looping.

Indexing example:

```
import magic_square as ms

a = ms.magic(5)

print a # a is an array
[[17 24  1  8 15]
 [23  5  7 14 16]
 [ 4  6 13 20 22]
 [10 12 19 21  3]
 [11 18 25  2  9]]

# Indexing example.  
b = a[a[:,1]>10]*10

print b
[[170, 240,  10,  80, 150],
 [100, 120, 190, 210,  30],
 [110, 180, 250,  20,  90]]
```

It should be clear how indexing can substantially improve your speed when analyzing one or more arrays.  It's a powerful tool...

Answer (score 0):

If these are aggregation statistics, consider using [Python Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). For example, if you want to do something to all the different `(foo, bar)` pairs, you can just group-by those items and then apply the vectorized NumPy operations:

```
import pandas, numpy as np
df = pandas.DataFrame(
                      {'foo':[1,2,3,3,5,5], 
                       'bar':['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'], 
                       'colA':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 
                       'colB':[7,8,9,10,11,12]})
print df.to_string()

# Computed average of 'colA' weighted by values in 'colB', for each unique
# group of (foo, bar).
weighted_avgs  = df.groupby(['foo', 'bar']).apply(lambda x: (1.0*x['colA']*x['colB']).sum()/x['colB'].sum())

print weighted_avgs.to_string()
```

This prints the following for just the data object:

```
  bar  colA  colB  foo
0   a     1     7    1
1   b     2     8    2
2   b     3     9    3
3   b     4    10    3
4   c     5    11    5
5   c     6    12    5
```

And this is the grouped, aggregated output

```
foo  bar
1    a      1.000000
2    b      2.000000
3    b      3.526316
5    c      5.521739
```